# libc.so crash on Galaxy S21 5G - React-Native

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, react-native

I am getting the following crash log on Crashlytics. I can not figure out a way to debug this.[image: crash log 2] [image: crash log] It has only been seen on Galaxy S21 5G. I found [a similar issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/33083) on this React-Native repo but there haven't been any updates. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Cience you found any solution? It's same happen for me.

Comment: Hi @Rajpal sorry for replying late, unfortunately I still don't know proper solution for me so I ended up upgrading the ReactNative version as a last measure, I believe this issue is being tracked [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/33083)